# Dropzone 5.0.0 example using new client side image resizing?

Tags: dropzone.js

As of version 5.0.0 there is now client side image resizing.

I haven't been able to find an example of this being implemented on dropzonejs.com

I'm hoping someone can provide a basic example.

Thanks